# TypeScript type representing everything but undefined

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0, tsc

I have a function like so:

```
export const logToStdout = function(v: NotUndefined){

  console.log(JSON.stringify({
        marker: '@json-stdio',
        value: v
   });
}
```

what I would like to have is a definition for NotUndefined that is everything but `undefined`.

You can see the problem when running:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify({value: ''}));
console.log(JSON.stringify({value: undefined}));
```

what would be kind of nifty would be:

```
export type NotUndefined = !undefined;
```

what is the right way to do this?

I see this related issue in on Github for TS: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7648

*I tried this methodology, but there is no error:*

[image]

**Before you complain**, here is the code/gist:
https://gist.github.com/ORESoftware/e138f1840302c79b4ffc5f961337c44b

Comment: Please insert that few lines of code as text, instead of screenshot and link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enable strict null checks, otherwise `null` and `undefined` are implicitly added as valid values for every type.

References:

- https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html

Comment: hmmm I guess it's up to the end user to implement that, I can do it for my library, but for users using my library, they are on their own I guess.

Comment: There is nothing you can do about. It is a compiler setting. Without `strictNullChecks` set to `true`, `undefined` *and* `null` are assignable to *every* type (well except `never`) and _bypass_ type checking whatsoever.